# ftplib.error_perm: 550 Requested action not taken

Tags: python, ftplib

Got this error while running my script: 
ftplib.error_perm: 550 Requested action not taken.

```
ftp = FTP()

HOST = 'some host here'
PORT = 'some port here'

ftp.connect(host=HOST, port=PORT)
ftp.login(user="some_user", passwd="pass")

out = 'ftp_files/'


filenames = ftp.nlst()
for file in filenames:
    file = file[::-1]
    file = file.split(' ')[0]
    file = file[::-1]    # file name is ready
    with open(out + file, 'wb') as f:
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file, f.write)
ftp.close()
```

I've changed pass, username, host and port in this example. They are correct in real. 
If anybody knows what the problem can be?

Comment: What is the content of `file` ?

Comment: XML files mostly.And some csv files.

Answer (score 0):

It falls only on one file that is empty. I still don't know if this was the problem, but i will look for anoher solution in my project. Current ftp isn's stable in work.